# Unexpected 404 from Scotty

Tags: url, haskell, routes, url-routing, scotty

I'm trying to use Scotty in Haskell, and following a tutorial, I could route a url like so:

```
get "/hello/:name" $ do
            name <- param "name"
            text ("Hello " <> name <> "!!")
```

However, what is the syntax to capture multiple route parameters? Neither of the following worked:

```
post "/newuser/:id/:name" $ do
            id <- param "id"
            name <- param "name"
            json $ User {userId = id, userName = name}

get "/users/{id}" $ do
            id <- param "id"
            json $ filter (matchesId id) allUsers
```

Comment: What error do you have? I don't see anything wrong. Be careful that `id` is already bound to a function

Comment: No error, just that the routes weren't being served (ok, so error 404 I guess) . Which one is the correct according to you?

Comment: first one should be working. I'm not aware of a `{param}` syntax. Maybe there is something wrong somewhere else. What url are you triyng?

Comment: Found the bracket syntax somewhere else. I'm try again in a few hours. Url was for example localhost:1337/newuser/3/bob

Comment: are you sure you are sending a `POST` request? You can test with `curl -i -XPOST http://localhost:1337/newuser/3/bob`

Comment: Ow, that's it, I forgot that, thanks.

Comment: Add an answer if you want to, else I'll add one explaining my error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP method is part of route matching in Scotty.
To match your `POST` route, you have to test it with a `POST` request, or Scotty will answer with a 404 http error.